# Node.js Child Process getting "Stuck"

Tags: multithreading, node.js, memory-leaks, cpu, processor

I'm building a web crawler in Node.js using the `npm crawler` package. My program right now creates 5 child processes which each instantiate a new Crawler, which crawls a list of URLS which the parent provides.

When it runs for about 15-20 minutes, it slows down to a halt and the processes' `STATE` column from the output of the `top` command reads `stuck` for all the children. [see below]

I have little knowledge of the `top` command, and the columns provided, but I want to know **is there a way to find out what is causing the processes to slow down by looking at the output of `top`?** I realize that it is probably my code that has a bug in it, but I want to know where I should start debugging: memory leak, caching issue, not enough children, too many children, etc.

Below is the entire output of `top`

```
PID    COMMAND      %CPU      TIME     #TH    #WQ   #PORT #MREG MEM    RPRVT  PURG   CMPRS  VPRVT  VSIZE  PGRP  PPID  STATE    UID       FAULTS    COW    MSGSENT    MSGRECV    SYSBSD     SYSMACH
11615  node         2.0       17:16.43 8      0     42    2519  94M-   94M-   0B     1347M+ 1538M  4150M  11610 11610 stuck    541697072 14789409+ 218    168        21         6481040    63691
11614  node         2.0       16:57.66 8      0     42    2448  47M-   47M-   0B     1360M+ 1498M- 4123M  11610 11610 stuck    541697072 14956093+ 217    151        21         5707766    64937
11613  node         4.4       17:17.37 8      0     44    2415  100M+  100M+  0B     1292M- 1485M  4114M  11610 11610 sleeping 541697072 14896418+ 215    181        22         6881669+   66098+
11612  node         10.3      17:37.81 8      0     42    2478  24M+   24M+   0B     1400M- 1512M  4129M  11610 11610 stuck    541697072 14386703+ 215    171        21         7083645+   65551
11611  node         2.0       17:09.52 8      0     42    2424  68M-   68M-   0B     1321M+ 1483M  4111M  11610 11610 sleeping 541697072 14504735+ 220    168        21         6355162    63701
11610  node         0.0       00:04.63 8      0     42    208   4096B  0B     0B     126M   227M   3107M  11610 11446 sleeping 541697072 45184     410    52         21         36376      6939
```

Here are the dependencies:

```
├── colors@0.6.2
├── crawler@0.2.6
├── log-symbols@1.0.0
├── robots@0.9.4
└── sitemapper@0.0.1
```

Sitemapper is one I wrote myself which could be a source for bugs.

Comment: "Stuck"? that's pretty odd, considering node.js is asynch... It should never be "stucK". Do you have a code snippet you could add to this question that might give us greater insight? What libraries are you using with node?

Comment: Yeah let me list the dependencies and update that question. There is a lot of code, so I didn't think it was beneficial to include it, but rather get a higher level understanding of where the issue could be coming from.